# Get nested element value from XML in Python using ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have an xml of the type:

```
<NAME F_NAME="BOGOTA">
  <SCHOOL NAME="DPS" ADDR="NYC" />
  <MED HOSP="ABC" FAMILY="IND">
    <PATIENT ID="10101022" WARD="10">
      <ADMIT TIME="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" DR_NAME="XYZ">
      </ADMIT>
    </PATIENT>
  </MED>
</NAME>
```

I tried accessing the elements by the below method:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> parsed_xml = ET.parse('test.xml')
>>> root = parsed_xml.getroot()
>>> for child in root.iter():
...     print(child.tag, child.attrib)
...
NAME {'F_NAME': 'BOGOTA'}
SCHOOL {'NAME': 'DPS', 'ADDR': 'NYC'}
MED {'HOSP': 'ABC', 'FAMILY': 'IND'}
PATIENT {'ID': '10101022', 'WARD': '10'}
ADMIT {'TIME': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', 'DR_NAME': 'XYZ'}
```

But this prints all the child tag values and it's attributes. How to get the nested tag name and it's values? For example, SCHOOL->NAME.

Comment: The example is slightly confusing, do you want to get `name` attribute from `school` tag?

Comment: Yes, but not doing if child.tag=="SCHOOL': name = child.attrib

Comment: what about `root.findall("SCHOOL[@NAME]")`

Comment: If you only want the School name and not whole element object, you can do `school_name = root.find("./SCHOOL").attrib["NAME"]`

Comment: This works. I tried to get the root element value by this approach like: root.find("./NAME").attrib["F_NAME"]. But it was throwing some error. How to get this using same approach?

Comment: its because you are triyng to search for `NAME` under your root, which is `NAME` so it is searching for `NAME/NAME` which obviously does not exist, do `school_name = root.find(".").attrib["F_NAME"]`

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thanks for the valuable response :)